# if and else for visible form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visibility

i have this code but return error

```
private void formshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (form1.Visible)                
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("This form is visible");
               }
           else
               {
                   Form2 f = new Form2();
                   f.Show();
               } 
        }
```

help me please

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Error 1 It should be a reference to an object for the property, method or field is not static 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Visible.get "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `form1` the type of the current instance? If so, change `if (form1.Visible)` to `if (this.Visible)` or simply `if (Visible)`.